# how to catch exception thrown by smooksTransformer in mule flow?

Tags: spring, mule

In mule flow i have a file inbound endpoint which reads .edi files and generates xml files.
If any exception is thrown while parsing edi file, i need catch it and send a custom error message to spring controller, from which mule flow is called. How to do this in mule integrated spring project?

Below are my mule flow end points:

```
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\smooks\test docs\in"
        pollingFrequency="3000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Incoming File"
        transformer-refs="SmooksTransformer">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="(.*).edi"
            caseSensitive="false" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\smooks\test docs\out" responseTimeout="10000" 
        doc:name="Outgoing File" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename].xml"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at you've shared of your flow, this "*spring controller, from which mule flow is called*" doesn't make sense: there is no way nor need to call the flow as then file inbound endpoint is a poller and will fire regularly without any need to call it.

Because this flow is not invoked synchronously, the only way to have a custom bit of code being informed in case an exception is thrown is to listen to Mule notifications. Creating a listener that listens for `[org.mule.context.notification.ExceptionNotification][1]` and calls a method on your controller bean should work.

The way you start Mule will be a problem though: you start it in its own context so the beans defined in Mule will have no way of reaching the beans in your existing Spring application context. [This documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Spring+Application+Contexts) page explains how you could resolve this by making the Mule application context a child of the existing Spring one, which would allow calling the controller.

If this is too complex for you. here is an alternative: add an exception strategy in your flow that sends errors to a one-way VM queue and have your Spring controller use the `muleClient` bean to regularly poll the content of this VM queue (with `request()`). That way you will bring the errors back into your main Spring context.

Comment: Hi David, my requirement is to call mule flow with a specific file name,i get the name of file as a query parameter to spring controller.Is it possible to remove poller from file inbound end point and call the flow explicitly from spring controller?

Comment: That's a completely different use case then, why isn't your question formulated this way? Anyway, in that case use an inbound VM endpoint in your flow and call it with `muleClient.send()`.

Comment: Inbound vm endpoint expects file to be sent in mesage not filename and it does not have a property to set the source directory of file.
`InputStream in = IOUtils.getResourceAsStream(inputFileName, this.getClass());
   message = muleClient.send("vm://EDITransformation", new DefaultMuleMessage(in, muleContext));`

Comment: `muleClient.send("vm://EDITransformation", in, Collections.singletonMap("sourceFileName", inputFileName))`

Comment: Dosoot Hi David, I am unable to catch the smooks exception thrown by transformer. As u suggested i have created a listner which extends ExceptionNotificationListner. In flow using catch-excpetion-strategy with enableNotification="true".

Comment: I am trying to access the exception in listener, But the listener was not notified on exception. 
SmooksException Exception does not come in hierarchy of MuleException. Is this an issue? How to handle exceptions other than mules's exception?

Comment: I you go the listener way, you do not need a specific exception strategy in the flow, just let it die and get notified of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your spring config that had your controller bean and use a custom exception strategy in your flow to pass details to your controller in it like:

```
<spring:ref bean="Controller" />
```

Comment: You mean import spring-config into mule-config. I did it in reverse way. I have existing spring application. I am trying to integrate mule into it. Used below code to integrate mule into spring app.                                                      `<beans:bean name="muleClient" class="org.mule.module.client.MuleClient" scope="singleton">
  <beans:constructor-arg value="META-INF/mule/mule-config.xml"/>
 </beans:bean>`                                                     From controller to start mule app using `muleClient.getMuleContext().start();`

Comment: just throw your exception from your custom exception strategy from a java component and catch that in your controller

Comment: I thought of using custom-exception-strategy but DefaultServiceExceptionStrategy is deprecated.